# Is it more secure to close the door turning the key twice?

Tags: household

Some door locks you can turn twice (or even three times!). Is there added security in doing so? Or would it basically take the same amount of time to break / open a lock?

NOTE: I'm not sure if I use the proper words, but I'm referring to putting in the key, and turning it completely (it's locked now), and then, turning it another round (the pin goes in deeper - it's even 'more' locked).

Comment: if the lock is made to lock with multiple turns then you need to repick it each turn if you don't lock the pins in place after the initial pick (with a skeleton key) all the rest will remain the same

Comment: According to the [FAQ](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/faq#questions), Skeptics.SE is for researching the evidence behind the claims you hear or read. This question doesn't appear to have any doubtful claims to investigate. Please edit it to reference a notable claim.

Comment: It's not about "anti-picking" security—it's about increasing the mechanical resistance, extending a deadbolt further into the door frame (or bolt receiver). It doesn't make it "more locked", it makes the door harder to jimmy or break down, particularly if the door is strong and the door frame is strengthened/reinforced. (And it doesn't do much good if your hinges are installed with 5/8" screws.)

Comment: I think that should be an answer, Stan.

Comment: @DJClayworth — It might be if it could be properly referenced, etc. Oddly, there aren't very many peer-reviewed sources and so forth for the construction trades, and vendor claims are what the questions are supposed to be questioning.